# Blazor Server App: can the server be kept running on Visual Studio

Tags: debugging, server, blazor

When the app is lunched on Visual Studio the server starts and the browser is launched.
When the browser is closed the debug session is closed and the server is stopped abruptly.

Is there a way in Visual Studio to keep the server running with all the browsers closed?

(the server establish TCP connections with various devices and I would like to see how it behaves with no clients)

Comment: There is an option in the application properties (Debug section) to launch without a browser. In VS2022 this has moved to creating a launch profile, but probably the same idea. This may be all you need.

Comment: Thanks topsail, that did the trick. In Project properties  --> Debug click Open Debug Launch Profiles UI and in there untick Launch Browser

Answer (score 0):

Any .NET (core/5/6) app can be run using the command line `dotnet run`

I typically have a command script added to my projects that calls `dotnet watch` so that the app runs in hot reload mode. This will continue to run even if VS is closed down, and will update or rebuild if you alter the source code.

More information:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/hot-reload?view=aspnetcore-6.0